# How to remove an element by name from a named vector?

Tags: r

How to remove an element from a named vector by name? e.g.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3)
names(v) <- c('a', 'b', 'c') 
# how to remove b?
v['b'] <- NULL # doesn't work
Error in v["b"] <- NULL : replacement has length zero
```

Comment: `v[names(v) != "b"]` Or `v[setdiff(names(v), "b")]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
v[names(v) != "b"]
#a c 
#1 3
```

Or with `setdiff`

```
v[setdiff(names(v), "b")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or we can use an index with `match`

```
v[-match("b", names(v))]
```